# extract domains from string using php

Tags: php

> w.gazetteherald.co.ukw.yorkherald.co.ukw.yorkpress.co.uk

I want to separate the domains from the above string.

Comment: In that string you could `explode()` on the spaces.

Comment: OK? What does the string look like, and what code have you tried?

Comment: there is no space between domain, once i posted questions its showing space

Comment: Your question is unclear. It's not even a question, is a request. What you want to do? What did you do so far?

Comment: m parsing html file and i have one table td which has domains separated by "<br>" but once i parse the html file these "<br>" going off and m getting this string

Comment: @UmakantMane You should show the original data and how you're parsing it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use explode function of php.

Documentation: http://php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php

```
explode('.', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

These domains cannot be separated by code.

`w.gazetteherald.co.ukw.yorkherald.co.ukw.yorkpress.co.uk` is a *perfectly valid* [FQDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name). So is `gazetteherald.co.ukw.yorkherald.co.ukw.yorkpress.co.uk`, `co.ukw.yorkherald.co.ukw.yorkpress.co.uk`, `ukw.yorkherald.co.ukw.yorkpress.co.uk`and so on.